# Show external IP in the title bar of TightVNC viewer

Tags: tightvnc

I connect from Windows to Ubuntu 16 using TightVNC viewer but it shows internal IP address in the titlebar.

One IP example is which I type in to connect : 23.239.40.81::5901

If I right click the title bar and select "Connection info" then it correctly shows the external IP address as "host".

Is there anyway to do show the real IP in the titlebar?

[image]